# python regex matching multilines using start and 1 or more endlines

Tags: regex, python-2.7

how can i match all lines between start line and one or more endlines,

let's say my string is :

```
My_string="""helloWorld
             .
             [wanted lines]
             .
             code/count: 1/11 22/22 33/33
             code/count: 4/44 55/55 6/666
              """
```

in above example the start line is "helloWorld' and  the end line is "\s+Code/Count: [\d+/\d+ \w+]+" ,

now the problem is :
1)if i do this :

```
re.search(r'helloWorld(.+?)\r?\n\s+Code/Count: [\d+/\d+ \w+]+\r?\n' ,My_string,re.DOTALL)
```

the match.group will be :

```
helloWorld
.
[wanted lines]
.
code/count: 1/11 22/22 33/33
```

2)if i do :

```
re.search(r'helloworld(.+?)\r?\n\s+Code/Count: [\d+/\d+ \w+]+\r?\n\s+Code/Count: [\d+/\d+ \w+]+' ,My_string,re.DOTALL)
```

the match.group will have both endlines (which is what i want)(code/count: 1/11 22/22 33/33 && code/count: 4/44 55/55 6/666) but if My_string has only one "code/count: 1/11 22/22 33/3" no match.group , i don't know how many  (code/count: 1/11 22/22 33/21) i have in My_string ,

any way to accomplish this ?

Comment: 6 hours and no response - that means the question is not clear. Please edit and show  what you want to match or achieve. A shot in the dark: [`helloWorld(.+?)\r?\n[ \t]*(?:Code/Count:(?: \d+/\d+)+(?:\r?\n)?)+`](https://regex101.com/r/vG8iZ5/1) - with DOTALL and IGNORECASE flags.

Answer (score 0):

You should use not greedy regex `*?` or `+?`.

In this way the regex matcher try to math as minimum as possible (instead of normally as mush as possible).

```
         helloWorld
         .
         [wanted lines]
         .
         code/count: 1/11 22/22 33/33
         code/count: 4/44 55/55 6/666
```

Using this regex: `helloworld$((?:.*\n)*?)^code/count:` with flag `re.MULTILINE` and `re.IGNORECASE`. will match what you need.

```
result=re.findall(r'helloworld$((?:.*\n)*?)^code/count:',my_strings,re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)
```

Check [Here](https://regex101.com/r/vV5tS6/2)

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish matching all "endlines", just specify the endline pattern as a repeatable group in parentheses with the quantifier `+`:

```
re.search(r'helloworld(.+?)(\s+Code/Count:[/ \w]+)+', My_string, re.DOTALL|re.I).group()
```